# The "Copy Text" button not working in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have made a button to copy text and for some reason it is not working

 This is the error that I am getting:-

```
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable 
    myFunction http://127.0.0.1:8000/home line 50729 > scriptElement:8
    onclick http://127.0.0.1:8000/home:1
```

**Here are my codes:-**

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 10%;">
<input type="hidden" value="/post/{{Auth::user()->uuid}}" id="myInput">

<!-- The button used to copy the text -->
<button  onclick="myFunction()">Copy Unique Code</button>


<script type="application/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
} 


</script>
</div>
```

Comment: The input element's type ('hidden') does not support selection.

Comment: it worked but when I first executed this code with the "hidden" it was working, how do i keep the text hidden now

Comment: use style `display: none`

Comment: it worked, if you can write this in answer I can close the question

Comment: Just did. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element's type ('hidden') does not support selection. Instead you can use css styling for it.

```
<input type="text" value="/post/{{Auth::user()->uuid}}" id="myInput" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy a text you can do something like this

```
<!-- add the text you want to copy inside the data-text attribute -->
<button id="copyBtn" data-text="Text to copy">Copy</button>

<script>
    const copyBtn = document.querySelector('#copyBtn');
    copyBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.value = copyBtn.dataset.text;
        document.body.appendChild(input);
        input.select();
        if(document.execCommand('copy')) {
            alert('Text Copied');
            document.body.removeChild(input);
        }
    });
</script>
```